# jquery one on() instead of bind() and live()

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I need handle events for static created and dynamic created elements.
solution for static created elements is:

```
$(".js-tag-close").on("click", function ()
{
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

for dynamic created:

```
$(".custom-tags-selector").on("click", ".js-tag-close", function ()
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

How can I handle both case in one on() ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: your second `on` will do the same as the first so you can remove the first

Answer (score 5):

The second way will work for both static elements and dynamic elements.

Why ?

Because you delegate the event handler execution to the container `.custom-tags-selector`. The handler will be executed as long as any descendant for which the specified selector `.js-tag-close` is valid is being clicked, no matter it exists already or is added dynamically.

The only condition is that the container on which you delegate exists in the DOM when your code runs.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/mjTQq/)**